# Show QSplitter child widgets titlebar

Tags: qt, qwidget, qsplitter

When I add `QWidget` to `QSplitter`, header/title bar of the child widget gets hidden automatically. is there a way to show it ??

Ex:

```
 QSplitter* sp = new QSplitter();
 QWidget* wid = new QWidget();
 wid->setWindowTitle("Mytitle);
 sp->addWidget(wid);
```

In this case wid title bar gets hidden automatically, I want to show it.

Comment: I think it's not possible, you must create you own frame. Only windows have a frame with titlebar (windows are widgets not embedded in a parent widget). http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html

Comment: Well, actually it is possible. You could add a QGraphicsView into your splitter, then add the widget to the graphics scene and make sure it always fills the entire scene. But before doing that, maybe explain what you actually want to achieve. For example, if what you want is a multiple-document interface, use QMdiArea.

Comment: @GeorgyPashkov I wanted to add multiple widgets to the parent widget (I added muliple QWidgets to the splitter with vertical policy)& for each child widget widget I want to show Title, close buttons.

Comment: @Durga, and when the user clicks the Close button, should the splitter pane get closed as well? Maybe you would be better off with a custom title bar in this case. It'll give you more control, and the look will not depend on the system theme

Comment: @GeorgyPashkov I can take care of all these things, i just need a way to show this title bar.. Using graphicsWindow, scene and all may complicate the things , I hope there should be a simpler way.. thnx for the response :-)